# From/by (what sounds better?)

Tags: word-usage

A boy asks a person a philanthropist why he helped a lot of people. So he replied:

> I get happiness and satisfaction ***by / from*** helping people.

So what will be used: from/by?

(I read this somewhere)

Comment: in could be used too, "I get happiness and satisfaction *in* helping people."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get happiness and satisfaction by/from helping people.

Either version is correct. You can't go wrong with either one. I can't say one sounds better than the other.